# How to delete a header from a QNetworkrequest?

Tags: qt, http, soap, qtcpsocket, qnetworkrequest

I would like to build a custom SOAP-Request with Qt.
For my specific SOAP-action packet I need to remove the
Accept-Language header which is automatically present in the QNetworkrequest.

It would be really handy to have the opposite of:

```
QNetworkRequest browseRequest;
browseRequest.setRawHeader(QByteArray("Accept-Language"), QByteArray("english"));
```

For example:

```
browseRequest.deletePartOfHeader(QByteArray("Accept-Language"));
```

Edit:
Went with a QTcpSocket and sent the needed String.
Found no other solution.

Comment: I found the following patch: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/47395/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't believe this is possible (yet) with QNetworkRequest.  See bug [QTBUG-9463](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-9463), "QNetworkRequest: Be able to unset some of the optional header entries".

The bug report's description mentions your case specifically:

> QNetworkRequest: Be able to unset some of the optional header entries
>   such as Accept-Encoding and **Accept-Language** as they do not have to be
>   in the header, but currently there is no way to unset them.

(Emphasis mine.)